# @GestureState cannot be used used as an attribute

Tags: swift, swiftui

In a project I want to declare a variable @GestureState, however I get the following error for no reason: "enum 'GestureState' cannot be used as an attribute".

I've worked with this kind of wrapper property before and didn't get this error at the time. 
If anyone has an idea where this error might come from, I'll take it.

```
@GestureState var selected = false // error here :/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happening because somewhere in the project you're creating an `enum` named `GestureState` rename it to something else and you're good to go.

Modify this:

```
enum GestureState { ... }
```

To this:

```
enum GestureStateType { ... }
```